# How to inherit schema properties from another schema?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I'm using ReDoc to visualize API documentation using an OpenAPI 2 (Swagger) JSON file. I'm trying to declare two request input parameters by including the first schema into the second one as follows:

```json
...
"definitions": {
    "list-request": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "token":{
                "type": "string",
                "format": "access-token",
                "required": true
            },
            "userId":{
                "type": "integer",
                "required": true,
                "format": "int32"
            },
            "mode": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "default": "lite",
                "enum": [
                    "lite",
                    "detailed"
                ]
            },
            ... // other peroperties
        },
        "xml": {
            "name": "list-request"
        }
    },
    "list-request-lite":{
        "$ref": "#/definitions/list-request",
        "properties":{
            "mode": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "enum": ["lite"]
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

But it does not work - the `list-request-lite` schema just shows the `mode` property and none of the `list-request` schema properties are included. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `allOf` to combine a `$ref` with other properties.

Also, the required properties need to be listed in the `required` array on the schema level. Individual properties don't have the `required` attribute.

```json
"definitions": {
  "list-request": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "token": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "access-token"
      },
      "userId": {
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int32"
      },
      "mode": {
        "type": "string",
        "default": "lite",
        "enum": [
          "lite",
          "detailed"
        ]
      }
    },
    "xml": {
      "name": "list-request"
    },
    "required": [     // <---- required properties for this schema
      "token",
      "userId"
    ]
  },

  "list-request-lite": {
    "allOf": [        // <---------
      {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/list-request"
      },
      {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "mode": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["lite"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```